# How to extend the timeout when using Watson's Tone Analyzer

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, ibm-watson

In a project that I am working on, I am trying to analyze 500 blocks of text via Watson's Tone Analyzer. The problem is, when I run the parallel 500 http calls, the service times out. Following is the code that is giving me issues:

```
function analyzeManyPosts(posts){

    var qPromise = q.defer();

    const count = posts.length;

    var promList = posts.map(function(post){
        // analyzeSinglePost is another function I wrote that returns a promise 
        // that works as intended
        return analyzeSinglePost(post); 
    });

    //Return a collection of all promises
    return q.all(promList);
}
```

When I call the above function I get a timeout error that reads `Error: connect ETIMEDOUT`

My two options are to either

- increase the timeout, or
- make sure that I only run call n after call n-1 is resolved.

I am looking for a way to do the first option, before defaulting to the second one.

Thank you!

Comment: If you use bluebird it has a `map` function with concurrency where you can tell it to only run 8 calls at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [throat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/throat) to limit the concurrent calls so that no one call is timed out. I did that the following way:

```
function analyzeManyPosts(posts){

    var qPromise = q.defer();

    const count = posts.length;

    //Limit to 50 calls at a time
    var promList = posts.map(throat(function(post, i){
        console.log(i);
        return analyzeSinglePost(post);
    }, 50));

    //Return a collection of all promises
    return q.all(promList);
}
```

This way only 50 calls are made at a time, avoiding the timeout when all 500 calls are made at once.